# Any idea about the fonts in this document?

Tags: fonts, templates

[image]The document is from 1965 (scanned image) and my guess is it was likely originally done via typewriter. What is the font(s) used in this document?

Comment: This isn’t really on topic here, but try https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ or http://www.identifont.com/.

Comment: Which image? No idea without ...

Comment: This could have been done in a different program as well, not necessarily (La)TeX. And if it's a scan, you're most likely not going to be able to retrieve any font information directly. You'll have to do some non-(La)TeX legwork yourself.